# Java StringBuilder with indexOf

Tags: java, stringbuilder, indexof

I'm programming a traditional hangman game in Java. What I'm currently stuck on is to find if the users character input is not a character within the `String`.

```
if(getLetters.indexOf(userCharInput)==-1) //getLetters is the StringBuilder, and the userCharInput is a String.
{
     playerCounter++;
}
```

This is the section that I seem to have trouble in, I've looked at different `indexOf` examples and I've formulated this to work with my program.

The problem is, It doesn't work. I set it so the player has 3 chances to guess the word, since the default word is "apple" I guessed 'a', 'p', and 'l', which leaves 'e' to be guessed. Now I intentionally make 3 incorrect guesses and it doesn't proc the next `else if`:

```
else if(playerCounter == 3)
{
    System.out.println("All lives are gone! Game Over!");
    playerCounter = 1; //resets the playerCounter to one.
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide complete program. Did u try to debug it?

Comment: Put `else if` within your `if(getLetters.indexOf(userCharInput)==-1)`.

Comment: @Shivam Kalra I tried that and it still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not working was because of the `indexOf` method being used improperly,it was partially because of the ordering of the if statements, but that was very miniscule to the primary issue. What had to be changed was the way I used the `indexOf` method.

ie. instead of `gletter.indexOf(character);` it should have been `word.indexOf(character);`
where `word` was the word that had to be guessed, and `gletter` was the `StringBuilder` used to keep track of user guesses.

Answer (score 3):

It's because when you keep guessing the wrong letter, the first `if` statement is evaluated to true:

```
if(getLetters.indexOf(userCharInput)==-1) //getLetters is the StringBuilder, and the userCharInput is a String.
{
     playerCounter++;
}
```

So you keep increasing playerCounter (beyond 3).  This means that your next statement is unreachable (once it's greater than 3, it's not going to get any smaller, at least with the code you have posted so far).  So `else if (playerCounter == 3)` may not be reachable.

Comment: Yeah you're right, fixed everything up but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which illustrates your current problem.

Comment: This was half of the reason why it wasn't working but was the closest to the solution I came across, with the help of @paulsm4.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your `else if` is part of another if statement that is getting true, so check that out.

Comment: It might have been that, but I did what @Shivam Kalra said and it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the Javadoc for StringBuilder:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Based on the code you've posted, I'm guessing:

1) You're saving the letters needed (e.g. the letters in the word "apple") to getLetters.

2) getLetters is type StringBuilder

3) if userCharInput is type "char", then indexOf() probably *won't* give the expected results

4) Substitute "if" for your "else if"

SUGGESTIONS:

Try changing "getLetters" to a "String", and see if that helps.

```
while (...) {
  ...
  //getLetters is the StringBuilder, and the userCharInput is a String.
  if(getLetters.indexOf(userCharInput)==-1)  {
     playerCounter++;
  }
  // Debug: comment this out once it's working
  System.out.println ("userCharInput=" + userCharInput + ", playerCounter=" + playerCounter);
  if(playerCounter == 3) {
    System.out.println("All lives are gone! Game Over!");
    playerCounter = 1; //resets the playerCounter to one.
    System.exit(0);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: userCharInput is a String according to the comment in the code at the top of this post

Comment: I didn't see it because the stupid comment scrolled off the right.  Nevertheless - your answer is correct. It won't fail until *after* playerCounter >= 3 *and* he gives at least one correct letter.  I've updated my post.

Comment: I tried putting the second `if` that you have withing the first since it seemed a bit simpler, it's not working, the only thing different from this solution to what I started off with was that it was an `else if`, I'll try your solution and get back to you.

Comment: And if course make sure that "playerCount" is incrementing in the first place. I'll make one more update to the code, to help you verify this (if you're not already using a debugger)...

Comment: Okay, I tried your solution and it still doesn't work, for now I think it's safer to make sure it check if the counter reaches 3 withing the first if statement. Still wondering why this isn't working, and I can only presume that `if(getLetters.indexOf(userCharInput)==-1)  {
     playerCounter++;
  }` is incrementing in the first place.

Comment: You don't have to presume :)  Put in the "System.out.println" shown above - or check in a debugger!

Comment: Alright, so I decided to do what you did and I found the real problem, java sees no problem with `if(gletters.indexOf(character)==-1)`, but the funny thing is it never get's into this. So I'm thinking that I'm not using the `indexOf` correctly. Some extra information, gletters is what used to be getLetters and userCharInput is now character, gletter is the StringBuilder and character is the user input (which is first validated with a regex so that only 1 letter character may pass).

Comment: Ah! I got it, I was blindsighted, the problem was exactly what I thought, what I really had to do was find the char index of the word that has to be guessed, what I was trying to do was find it in the StringBuilder which stores all user inputs! Thank you all again for your time and effort!